# Is it possible to play a external (e.g. from youtube) flash-video with html5 on my site?

Tags: html5, video, flash

I would like to use my site as a "gateway" for watching flash-videos in HTMl5.. Is this possible? What are the requirements?

Comment: First requirement: make sure you are not violating the terms of service for those sites.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app that already does this called [skyfire](http://www.skyfire.com/).

For example, on the iPhone, pulls out requests to flash video files and converts them server-side into HTML5 and re-embeds them into the page.

I haven't tried it, as its reviews are a bit rubbish at the moment (supposedly only works on certain websites), but its a proof of concept that it can be done.